# JavaScript not working on page load

Tags: javascript, html

I was working with an html page now i am trying to rewrite a div style to another style it'll look like this `<div class="fs-stretcher" style="width: 1170px; height: 480px;"></div>`. for that i am using java script like this

```
<script>
    window.onload=document.getElementsByClassName('fs-stretcher')[0].setAttribute("style","width: 0px; height: 0px; background-color: yellow;")
    </script>
```

but it is not working somebody please help me to fix this.

Comment: It's pretty dangerous to have just that function for your `window.onload` event. A better way would be to place your `script` tag(s) just about the closing body tag `</body>`. The elements would have been loaded by that time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assign a function reference to `window.onload`.

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementsByClassName('fs-stretcher')[0].setAttribute("style", "width: 0px; height: 0px; background-color: yellow;")
};
```

your code is executing the statement `document.getElementsByClassName....` and assigns the value returned by `setAttribute` to `onload`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to place the script after you div.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="fs-stretcher" style="width: 1170px; height: 480px;">adv</div>
<script>
    window.onload = document.getElementsByClassName('fs-stretcher')[0].setAttribute("style", "width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: yellow;")
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This will also work fine.  But if you use  `window.onload =function(){-----}` is best way as answer above by [Arun P johny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny).

Answer (score 0):

window onload is a function, and you should need to bind a function to this event.

so try:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementsByClassName('fs-stretcher')[0].setAttribute("style", "width: 0px; height: 0px; background-color: yellow;")
};
```

or you can create a function

```
function setElementOnLoad() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('fs-stretcher')[0].setAttribute("style", "width: 0px; height: 0px; background-color: yellow;")
};
```

and bind it to onload of body tag:

```
<body onload="setElementOnLoad()">
```